# Is this eRupee email from my bank a scam?

Tags: india, scams, currency, online-banking, inr-indian-rupee

I received an email like this, supposedly from my bank.

[image: Email From My Bank]

It is unclear to me if this email is just some kind of scam. On the one hand, GMail seems to have put a blue checkmark, indicating that the email is from the actual bank. On the other hand, the email is poorly formatted. They have inserted an image instead of actually providing the text! This means that the links are not clickable.

Is this a scam?

I am also unsure what the eRupee is. If I can manipulate my Rupee account in my bank using the internet, isn't that just regular internet banking? I have seen an [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rupee) about this, but it seems to make no sense.

EDIT: Two more pieces of information:

- Yes, I do banking with these people.
- I have a friend who has received the same email. He also does banking with them. (But it is not surprising; this is a major bank in India.)

Comment: In any case where you are unsure if an email from a supposed institution is real, the answer is *always* to first go to the main website of that institution, and look for the advertised program there. No idea of the legitimacy of this particular item. Note that you state one red flag is that the links are not clickable - I will warn you that the *worst* thing you can do with suspected scam / spam emails is to click links. **DONT CLICK LINKS IN UNKNOWN EMAILS**. If needed, call the main hotline [number determined by googling them, NEVER by calling numbers provided in that email].

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's a scam.

It seems very suspicious, especially sending a message as a pure image. Is the image itself a clickable link? If so, if you hover over it, does the URL point back to a legitimate URL of the bank? (pay special attention to dots, dashes, underscores, etc, there's a huge difference between bank.sbi.co.in and bank-sbi.co.in)

My guess is that the message is an image because they don't want you to click on the link or even hover over it and see the URL. They want you to scan the QR code mentioned at the bottom (not included in the image you posted but presumably there) which will begin the scam.

But if you're in doubt you can always call up the bank and ask them. (Not using any number that might have been provided in this email, mind you!). I think they'll tell you that they never send out emails requiring you to click on links or provide login / identifying details.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever sent this doesn’t even know your name. See how it says “Dear Customer” and not “Dear Agnishom” or “Dear Mr. Chattopadhyay”?

The story that *you* have been selected is pure nonsense.

But there is really a simple method. Find a phone number for your bank’s fraud department and call them.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it isn't a scam, it is definitely spam.

It claims you are an existing customer. Is this true? Do you do business with this company? If so call them using the contact information you have from them ESPECIALLY if it differs from what is in the email and confirm.

Comment: Yes, I am a customer. I do banking with them.